# fstrim wont run in a cronjob

Tags: disk-management

I have the following cronjob setup

```
@daily /root/trim.sh
```

/root/trim.sh

```
fstrim -av
```

but it just doesn't run. It does when run `/root/trim.sh` manually. It has `chmod +x` permissions. What is causing this?

Comment: Most likely because `/sbin` is not in the cron path; try changing the script to `/sbin/fstrim -av` or define an appropriate `PATH`

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sbin` was missing `/sbin/fstrim -av`

Comment: Why are your inventing new unique bicycle? The `fstrim` already has SystemD timer [`/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/util-linux/filelist) for this purpose running weekly, which is enough.

Comment: It's not enough for me

Comment: Same, not enough for me either.